# Error while setting up the Ionic Framework in the first step of installing cardova

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

Am getting the below error while setting the ionic framework in the first step of installing cardov, this is the below error i got while running the command 
"$ sudo npm install -g cordova" in the nodejs

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:236:25)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:441:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:219:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:561:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:838:14)
```

Please help me out with this error.

Comment: Remove "$ " from the command. "$" is only used in manuals / tutorials to indicate the command line.

Comment: I had run it without the $, it was the error.

Comment: make sure you have active internet connection and access to npmjs registry